# R: apply() function in with() function

Tags: r, apply, with-statement

Suppose a dataset where 10 participants have filled out a questionnaire with 3 items, x, y, and z.

```
ss <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))
```

I want to compute the mean of these items for each person (personal mean).
I can easily do that this way:

```
ss$personalmean <- rowMeans(ss[c("x", "y", "z")])
```

or this way:

```
ss$personalmean <- apply(ss[c("x", "y", "z")], 1, mean)
```

But suppose I want to be able to do that in the with function. Then I run into problems.

This works:

```
with(ss, (x+y+z)/3)
```

But this doesn't:

```
with(ss, rowMeans(c(x,y,z)))
with(ss, apply(c(x,y,z), 1, mean))
```

I don't understand why. The example here is trivial, but in short, I would like to use the function `apply()` within the function `with()`.

Apologies if someone posted a good answer to that question somewhere, but googling what I'm looking for isn't easy given that "with" is a pretty generic term.

Comment: Both `apply` and `rowMeans` work on matrices. Does `c(x,y,z)` look like a matrix?

Comment: You need `cbind` instead of `c`

Comment: @akrun, thank you for this answer. Would you mind entering it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Frank mentioned in the comments, the `apply` and `rowMeans` work with matrix/data.frame.  So, if we want to use `with`, instead of `c`, `cbind` converts it to `matrix`,

```
with(ss, rowMeans(cbind(x,y,z)))
with(ss, apply(cbind(x,y,z), 1, mean))
```